# Please identify this angular typeface?

Tags: font-identification

what is font of this image text?

Every one, please help me which font name is of attach this image text[image] ?

Advance thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The font is highly suggestive to [Metamorphous font](http://www.ffonts.net/Metamorphous.font?text=market) (free):

[image]

Comment: Nailed it. Should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use http://fontedge.matton.se/ . Additional information about how to identify a font can be found here: http://www.findafont.com/ . According to FontEdge the most likely result is `FF Eureka CE`.

Comment: Never heard of Find a Font...great resource! Thanks for sharing.